# How to deal with multicollinearity in a Translog Production Function

Tags: multicollinearity

What are the different methods for dealing with multicollinearity in a translog production function?

I have seen several methods such as:

1. Checking for variance inflation factor (VIF) and ensuring that it is less than 10 therefore, if VIF > 10, eliminate the variables in a step-wise way?
2. Maintain either the squares or the cross products depending on which fits data best. However, this might not be useful since most of the time the full model is a better fit.
3. Standardize the variables by the mean and estimating again. If there are still VIF>10, eliminate step-wise by VIF?

How do I deal with the issue of multicollinearity in my dataset? 
I know that translog is a better fit than Cobb-Douglas in my data but am faced with the multicollinearity challenge.  What would be a way forward?